# How to convert JavaRDD<<List<String>> to JavaPairRDD<String, String>

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have a JavaRDD when I print it my data looks like this
[[String1,String2,String3],[String4],[String5,String6],[String7,String8,String9]]

Each String is in turn a pipe separated strings. I can split each string to form a key and value.

How can I convert this RDD to a JavaPairRDD?

Comment: Basically you could use `mapToPair`, could you tell more details? Such as from where you extract your keys etc.

Comment: Thanks Yuan. Each String have sub strings like String1 = subStringString1|subString2|subString3 and so on. When I use mapToPair and start iterating through this RDD at every step I get a list of Strings not an individual string.

so what I did is

Comment: is there any separator between sub strings? or length of sub strings are fixed or not?

Comment: so what I did is

List<Tuple2<String,String>> newList = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String,String>>();
  List<List<String>> listOfList = rdd.collect(); 
  for(List<String> list : listOfList){
   for(String row : list){
    String [] rowElement = StringUtils.split(row,"~");
    String rowKey = rowElement[0]+"|"+rowElement[2];
    newList.add(new Tuple2<String, String>(rowKey, row));
   }
  }
  
  // Converting List of Tuples to JavaPairRDD
  JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRDD = jsc.parallelizePairs(newList, 1);

Comment: The for loop above is not part of any function. I want to do that as part of some function rather than operating on lists.

Comment: yes there is a separator between sub strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have such data in `JavaRDD<List<String>>`:

```
List_0: ["sub10~sub11~sub12","sub20~sub21~sub22","sub30~sub31~sub32"]
List_1: ["sub40~sub41~sub42"]
```

Where `~` is the separator.

And you want to flat the lists and group the first and the third sub string with `|` as the key for each input string, then store pairs in `JavaPairRDD<String,String>`:

```
key: "sub10|sub12"    value: "sub10~sub11~sub12"
```

**You could achieve this by using `flatMap` and then `mapToPair`:**

```
rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<List<String>,String>() {
    public Iterable<String> call(List<String> li) throws Exception {
        return li;
    }
}).mapToPair(new PairFunction<String,String,String>() {
    public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws Exception {
        String[] ss = s.split("~");
        return new Tuple2<String,String>(ss[0] + "|" + ss[2], s);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow below code snippet for transforming JavaRDD<K> into JavaPairRDD<K,V>

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Sensor> deviceRdd = sensorRdd.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Sensor, Integer, Sensor>() {

            public Tuple2<Integer, Sensor> call(Sensor sensor) throws Exception {
                Tuple2<Integer, Sensor>  tuple = new Tuple2<Integer, Sensor>(Integer.parseInt(sensor.getsId().trim()), sensor);
                return tuple;
            }
        });
```