# Converting JavaRDD<List<String>> to JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a `JavaRDD<List<String>>` and I want it to become a `JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>`, where the String is each element included in the lists of the original JavaRDD, and the Integer is a constant (1).
Is it possible to do something like that?
PS: already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393363/how-to-convert-javarddliststring-to-javapairrddstring-string), but didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use flatMapToPair

```
        JavaRDD<List<String>> rdd = ...;

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> flatMapToPair = rdd.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<List<String>, String, Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> call(List<String> t) throws Exception {
                List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String str : t) {
                    result.add(new Tuple2<>(str, 1));
                }
                return result;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> listRdd = null; //assign
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rdd = listRdd.flatMap(list -> list)
     .mapToPair(string -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(string, 1));
```